# Symfony get original user after impersonate another

Tags: symfony, impersonation

I'm using Symfony 3.4 and I'm working with the Impersonate user feature : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/impersonating_user.html

I need when I impersonate an user to get the original user.. I don't know how can I do that.

During impersonation, the user is provided with a special role called ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN, is there a way to change this role ?

For example if my original user is ROLE_ADMIN, the special role is ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN, but if my original user is ROLE_SOMETHING, the custom role should be : ROLE_PREVIOUS_SOMETHING

I just need to have a way to get the original user or at least get his roles.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
public function isImpersonatorAdmin()
{
    $impersonatorUser = false;

    if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN')) {
        foreach ($this->security->getToken()->getRoles() as $role) {
            if ($role instanceof SwitchUserRole) {
                $impersonatorUser = $role->getSource()->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $impersonatorUser;
}
```

This function return true if the impersonator is ROLE_ADMIN.

Comment: `SwitchUserRole` is deprecated in favour of `SwitchUserToken` - since Symfony 4.3 you can fetch the original user with `$impersonatorUser = $token->getOriginalToken()->getUser();`